# How to create class with data from DB with c#

Tags: c#, .net, class, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a C# class whose attributes are rows in a database table with ADO.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346910/how-to-create-a-c-class-whose-attributes-are-rows-in-a-database-table-with-ado-n)

At the moment I have the following class:

```
public class myActions
{
    public const string Create = "Create";
    public const string Read = "Read";
    public const string Update = "Update";
    public const string Delete = "Delete";
}
```

However, if the table called Action in the DB changes (adds or deletes possible actions), I do not want to modify the application in order to support the new action. So, my question is: how to keep this class updated with the actions stored in the DB and be able to use this actions throughout the application?

Update: The table in the database has only two columns: idAction, Name.

Comment: Have you tried working with LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: Not really. All my interaction with the DB is done with ADO.NET. But, if you can think of a solution with those tools, I am willing to try it!

Comment: for clarity, can you show the table columns as you have in the databas?

Comment: it seems to me that you use this class as a anti-magic-string-pattern (why not static?) - if so, that is if this is just to help you with intellisense then no, I don't think you can do this in a db

Comment: If the DBA knows what they are doing, they will never add or remove from these actions.  See: [this Wikipedia article on CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).  They may not all be available for all data, but they are the only ones that will exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are not using the database, but instead creating a class which mirrors the data you have in a database table.

You should start by understanding the notions of using data in your application.

For a quick start, I recommend these videos from Microsoft: [Beginner's Guide to the ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907).
In 30 minutes you will have the basic learnings you need to start building applications with data.

Comment: Come on! The only reason why I am doing this class like that is because I do not know how to get it dynamically from the DB, and still, I need to use that class throughout the application.

Comment: Generally code-gen is useful for the DB *schema*, but not for the data itself :)  That's why stuff like the Entity Framework and its ability to generate code from the DB schema exists.

Comment: @Alejandro: Then this answer is exactly what you need to read.  Don't duplicate the data - write code that reads the data from the DB.

Comment: @Alejandro: Entity Framework provides what you are asking. It will create a class which contains properties that reflect the fields on your table. It will provide ways to dynamically get your data from the database and allow you to work with it in your application. Check it out.

Comment: @Nelson I will have a look at it right now and keep you posted! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can have properties of a class added, removed or changed based on what is in a DB? If so, the only way I could suggest is that your myActions class is a class that is built in DEV time by some sort of code generator. Bear in mind that if elsewhere in your code you are referencing myActions.Create and "Create" was removed from the DB you could not compile.

If you are suggesting that you want those actions to change at runtime then you consider making your myActions class something like this:

public class myActions
{

```
public List<string> ActionList = List<string>();

public myActions(){
   //some code here to populate your list from the actions in your db
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps consider throwing your myActions class into the Cache and always access it from there. So, when you update the list in your admin suite, change the myActions object in your Cache - this will save always popualting the object.