# How to create a C# class whose attributes are rows in a database table with ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, class, ado.net, attributes

Is it possible?

Please note I am not using LINQ nor Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also check out [Dapper-Dot-Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) - a very lightweight and very capable "micro ORM" which - incidentally - is used to run this site here.

It's quite fast, a single *.cs file, works with your usual T-SQL commands and returns objects - works like a charm, it's very fast, very easy to understand, no big overhead - just use it and enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite is done using the **dynamic** object featured in .NET4 via [Rob Conery's Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) library. Like Dapper-Dot-Net it is small.

Answer (score 1):

By going old school you can use Datasets to create strongly typed data table classes that mirror your database entirely right down to the relationships. It's a precursor to LINQ/EF that auto-generates a lot of bloated code but they're very handy for maintaining your field names, data types, data constraints and performing easily configured rapid updates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(v=VS.100).aspx